# Enabling company-mode with variable setup

Tags: company-mode

I want to enable and disable `company-mode`.  Would I have to reset setup variables, everytime I want to enable `company-mode`?  Should I call `company-setup` before calling `company-enable`.  Is the placement of `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)` correct as part of setup?

```
(defun company-setup ()
  "Text completion-at-point drop-down framework displaying
possible candidates at cursor point as one types."

  (interactive)

  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)

  (setq company-backends '(company-dabbrev company-dabbrev-code))

  (setq company-dabbrev-other-buffers 'all)
  (setq company-dabbrev-ignore-case 'keep-prefix)

  (setq company-dabbrev-code-other-buffers 'all)
  (setq company-dabbrev-code-ignore-case t)
  (setq company-dabbrev-code-everywhere t)
   
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode))

(defun company-enable ()
  "Disables company completion"
  (interactive)
  (company-mode 1))
```

Comment: The function `company-setup` is enabling `company-mode` globally, unlike `company-enable`, ignoring the other customizations. They have different implications. What do you want to do? If your goal is to call the functions interactively, then you can avoid the hook and directly call `(global-company-mode 1)`.

Comment: I want to enable and disable company-mode globally at will, with the `dabbrev` settings.  What does `company-mode` do that conflicts with `global-company-mode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should enable `dabbrev` customizations with `company-mode`.

```
(with-eval-after-load "company"
  (setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2
        company-backends '(company-dabbrev company-dabbrev-code)
        company-dabbrev-other-buffers 'all
        company-dabbrev-ignore-case 'keep-prefix
        company-dabbrev-code-other-buffers 'all
        company-dabbrev-code-ignore-case t
        company-dabbrev-code-everywhere t))
```

You can now enable/disable `company-mode` globally "at will" with "M-x global-company-mode". You can use the `after-init-hook` if you want to have the mode enabled on startup.

Comment: I still cannot understand the difference between `company-mode` and `global-company-mode`.

Comment: That would be a perfectly good question to ask - as a *question*, not parenthetically in a comment.